# Grails String simple handling

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, grails, groovy

Having class Message as below:

```
public class Message { 
     private String text; 
     public Message(String text) { 
          this.text = text;
     } 
     public int getLength() { 
          return text.length()
     } 
}
```

I want to create another class with the following functions:

**Function 1:** sort messages in folders and subfolders for each user

**Function 2:** For each user displayed by folder:

- The Total number of messages in the folder and all its subfolders
- The Average length of messages in the folder and all its subfolders

**Note:**
A subfolder can contain subfolders, a restriction to a certain depth is undesirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I highly recommend is to update the question's title so that it reflects what you're asking for. Your challenge has little to do with String handling, and there's nothing simple about it.

Fortunately, Groovy has some neat utilities which can handle this sort of challenge.

## NodeBuilder

With Groovy's [NodeBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/NodeBuilder.html) you can create a tree of objects. The tree capable of representing the messages and a folder structure. Here it is in action:

```
import groovy.util.NodeBuilder
import groovy.util.Node

def root = new NodeBuilder().root {
    message 'world'
    message 'hello'

    'John' {
        'Work' {
            message 'TPS report'
        }

        'Secret Stuff' {
            message 'plea to mistress'
            message 'rejection from ex mistress'
        }
    }    

   'Jane' {
       message 'John, I know about her!'
   }
}
```

With an instance of this tree you can use [GPath](http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath) to perform the functions you requested:

### Function 1: Sorting

The sorting is not done recursively. Instead, it's done on demand.

```
// Sort the messages in the root of the tree, on the fly.
assert root.message.toSorted { it.value() }.toString() == '[message[attributes={}; value=hello], message[attributes={}; value=world]]'
```

### Function 2a: Total number of messages

```
// Count the number of messages within the 'John' folder; including 'Work' and 'Secret Stuff' folders.
assert root.John.'**'.message.size() == 3
```

### Function 2b: Average message length

```
// Calculate the average length of the messages in the 'John' folder: 52 / 3 = 17.3333333333
assert root.John.'**'.message.sum { it.value().size() } / root.John.'**'.message.size() == 17.3333333333
```

### Bonus: Accessing a specific message

```
// Access the first message in the 'Jane' folder.
assert root.Jane.message[0].value() == 'John, I know about her!'
```

In all of these cases, I did not use your Message class. But it's easy to use your Message class instead by using a sub-class of NodeBuilder.

## MessageTreeBuilder

The tree can be populated with Message instances with a custom builder. But first, lets improve the Message class.

```
@groovy.transform.Canonical
public class Message { 
     String text; 

     int size() { 
          return text.size()
     } 
}
```

And here's the MessageTreeBuilder

```
class MessageTreeBuilder extends NodeBuilder {
    Object createNode(Object name, Object value) {
        def payload = name == 'message' ? new Message(value) : value

        [currentNode, name, payload] as Node
    }
}
```

Yes, that's the entire class.

Then, you can use the **same exact tree**, but using an instance of MessageTreeBuilder instead of NodeBuilder.

```
// Sort the messages in the root of the tree, on the fly.
assert root.message.toSorted { it.value() }.toString() == '[message[attributes={}; value=Message(hello)], message[attributes={}; value=Message(world)]]'

// Count the number of messages within the 'John' folder; including 'Work' and 'Secret Stuff' folders.
assert root.John.'**'.message.size() == 3

// Calculate the average length of the messages in the 'John' folder: 52 / 3 = 17.3333333333
assert root.John.'**'.message.sum { it.value().size() } / root.John.'**'.message.size() == 17.3333333333


// Access the first message in the 'Jane' folder.
assert root.Jane.message[0].value() instanceof Message 
assert root.Jane.message[0].value().text == 'John, I know about her!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement class for folder first. Once you are done with that. Implement Comparable and override compareTo() function. Which compares messages. YOu can access this blog to understand how to use compareTo()

http://www.javatpoint.com/Comparable-interface-in-collection-framework